# How to use redirect without flicker in Nuxt App?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js, vuex

I have nuxt js application, I have implemented user authorization with vuex.
When a user clicks on nuxt link  in navigation bar

```
<nuxt-link to="/profile">Profile</nuxt-link>
```

I check if a user is logged in or not. If not -> redirect to login page, if yes -> stay on the same page "Profile"
The is a flicker before checking vuex state. Profile page appears on milliseconds before redirect to login page

**How can I fix it?**

Navigation Bar:

```
<nuxt-link to="/profile">Profile</nuxt-link>
```

**Profile Page:**

```
<template>
  <div class="profile">
    <h1>Profile</h1>
    <p> Content</P>
  </div>
</template>

beforeCreate() {

    if (!this.isUserLogged) {
      this.$router.push({name: 'login', path: '/login'})
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('login', ['isUserLogged']),
  },
```

**Vuex:**

```
export const state = () => ({
  isUserLogged: false,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if the user is already logged in when the navbar component is rendered the first time. If the user is already logged in just disable the link. If the user isn't logged in you can disable the link by re-rendering the navbar component after he logged in successfully. Alternatively you could dynamically disable or enable the link when the user logs in or out.